# Extracting Text between Two Strings in a Huge Ordered Text File

Tags: text-processing, grep, sort

We have a huge text file containing millions of ordered timestamped observations and given the start point and the end point, we need **a fast method** to extract the observations in that period.

For instance, this could be part of the file:

```
"2018-04-05 12:53:00",28,13.6,7.961,1746,104.7878,102.2,9.78,29.1,0,2.432,76.12,955,38.25,249.9,362.4,281.1,0.04
"2018-04-05 12:54:00",29,13.59,7.915,1738,104.2898,102.2,10.01,29.53,0,1.45,200.3,952,40.63,249.3,361.4,281.1,0.043
"2018-04-05 12:55:00",30,13.59,7.907,1734,104.0326,102.2,10.33,28.79,0,2.457,164.1,948,41.39,249.8,361.3,281.1,0.044
"2018-04-05 12:56:00",31,13.59,7.937,1718,103.0523,102.2,10.72,31.42,0,1.545,8.22,941,42.06,249.4,361.1,281.1,0.045
"2018-04-05 12:57:00",32,13.59,7.975,1719,103.1556,102.2,10.68,29.26,0,2.541,0.018,940,41.95,249.1,360.1,281.1,0.045
"2018-04-05 12:58:00",33,13.59,8,1724,103.4344,102.2,10.35,29.58,0,1.908,329.8,942,42.65,249.5,361.4,281.1,0.045
"2018-04-05 12:59:00",34,13.59,8,1733,103.9831,102.2,10.23,30.17,0,2.59,333.1,948,42.21,250.2,362,281.2,0.045
"2018-04-05 13:00:00",35,13.59,7.98,1753,105.1546,102.2,10.17,29.06,0,3.306,332.4,960,42,250.4,362.7,281.1,0.044
"2018-04-05 13:01:00",36,13.59,7.964,1757,105.3951,102.2,10.24,30.75,0,2.452,0.012,962,42.03,250.4,362.4,281.1,0.044
"2018-04-05 13:02:00",37,13.59,7.953,1757,105.4047,102.2,10.31,31.66,0,3.907,2.997,961,41.1,250.6,362.4,281.1,0.043
"2018-04-05 13:03:00",38,13.59,7.923,1758,105.4588,102.2,10.28,29.64,0,4.336,50.19,962,40.85,250.3,362.6,281.1,0.042
"2018-04-05 13:04:00",39,13.59,7.893,1757,105.449,102.1,10.27,30.42,0,1.771,12.98,962,41.73,249.8,362.1,281.1,0.043
"2018-04-05 13:05:00",40,13.6,7.89,1757,105.4433,102.1,10.46,29.54,0,2.296,93.7,962,43.02,249.9,361.7,281,0.045
"2018-04-05 13:06:00",41,13.59,7.915,1756,105.3322,102.1,10.52,29.53,0,0.632,190.8,961,43.64,249.3,361.5,281,0.045
"2018-04-05 13:07:00",42,13.6,7.972,1758,105.4697,102.1,10.77,29.49,0,0.376,322.5,961,44.69,249.1,360.9,281.1,0.046
"2018-04-05 13:08:00",43,13.6,8.05,1754,105.233,102.1,11.26,28.66,0,0.493,216.8,959,44.8,248.4,360.1,281.2,0.047
```

If we want the datapoints between "2018-04-05 13:00:00" and "2018-04-05 13:05:00", the output should be:

```
"2018-04-05 13:00:00",35,13.59,7.98,1753,105.1546,102.2,10.17,29.06,0,3.306,332.4,960,42,250.4,362.7,281.1,0.044
"2018-04-05 13:01:00",36,13.59,7.964,1757,105.3951,102.2,10.24,30.75,0,2.452,0.012,962,42.03,250.4,362.4,281.1,0.044
"2018-04-05 13:02:00",37,13.59,7.953,1757,105.4047,102.2,10.31,31.66,0,3.907,2.997,961,41.1,250.6,362.4,281.1,0.043
"2018-04-05 13:03:00",38,13.59,7.923,1758,105.4588,102.2,10.28,29.64,0,4.336,50.19,962,40.85,250.3,362.6,281.1,0.042
"2018-04-05 13:04:00",39,13.59,7.893,1757,105.449,102.1,10.27,30.42,0,1.771,12.98,962,41.73,249.8,362.1,281.1,0.043
"2018-04-05 13:05:00",40,13.6,7.89,1757,105.4433,102.1,10.46,29.54,0,2.296,93.7,962,43.02,249.9,361.7,281,0.045
```

Regular tools like `grep` or `sed` or `awk` are not optimized to be applied to sorted files. So they are not fast enough for. A tool which uses a binary search would be ideal for this type of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For very large files, you could exploit the natural order of the prefix timestamp to use the `look` utility to perform a fast binary search for the largest common prefix of the `start` and `end` strings. This can then be followed by `awk`/`sed` post-processing to extract lines of interest from `look`'s output

in `bash`

```
export start='"2018-04-05 13:00:00"'
export end='"2018-04-05 13:05:00"'
#determine common prefix ("2018-04-05 13:0 in this example)
common_prefix=$(awk 'BEGIN {
   start=ENVIRON["start"]; end=ENVIRON["end"];
   len=length(start) > length(end)? length(end): length(start); 
   i=1;
   while (i <= len && substr(ENVIRON["start"], i, 1) == substr(ENVIRON["end"], i, 1)) {
       ++i
   }
    print(substr(start, 1, i-1))
}' </dev/null
)
#the -b option to look forces binary search. 
#My version of look on Ubuntu needs this flag to be passed, 
#some other versions of look perform a binary search by default and do not support a -b.
look -b "$common_prefix" file | awk '$0 ~ "^"ENVIRON["start"],$0 ~ "^"ENVIRON["end"]'
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but it is not fast enough for a huge file, let's say a 100GB+ file.

Comment: @vahid-dan, check the updated solution

Comment: Thanks, @iruvar! Worked like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Print lines between "2018-04-05 13:00:00" and "2018-04-05 13:05:00"

```
sed -n '/2018-04-05 13:00:00/,/2018-04-05 13:05:00/p' file
```

or

```
sed -n /"2018-04-05 13:00:00"/,/"2018-04-05 13:05:00"/p file
```

Grep for start date "2018-04-05 13:00:00" and output the next 5 lines (=5 minutes), `-m1` stops searching after the first match.

```
grep -m1 -A5 '2018-04-05 13:00:00' file
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but it is not fast enough for a huge file, let's say a 100GB+ file.

Comment: If you need to extract lots of lines it might make sense to split the file and note the first and last line of each part. Or feed a database with the timestamps as SQL TIMESTAMP or DATETIME and index (b-tree).

Comment: Thank you @freddy. Actually, the file is merged from several smaller files but I'm not sure working with several smaller files is faster than a single large file. We are looking for a general solution that can be applied to any size of data.